# Resetting password of a locked out of Windows 7 VM image running on a ESXI Server

Tags: windows, password-recovery

While Setting up the group edit policy in a windows 7 OS running on vmware ESXI server. I have enabled login via smart card authentication.Now that Iam logged out of the system and the smart card authentication failing for some unknown reason.

Iam basically locked out of the Win7 VM image.Reverting back the VM can help, But the VM has some important configurations running on it which would be lost.

Please suggest any appropriate help for the same, to unlock the win7 VM image on ESXI server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get Hiren Boot CD ISO image and mount it. Adjust your VM to enter BIOS on next reboot. In BIOS make it boot from CD before HDD. Then run the password reset tools in the Hiren CD.